# What error with the if condition?

Tags: php

`echo $approver;` outputs "Supervisor" on webpage, but the code `echo "Supervisor is working <br />"` does not output anything.

```
$approver = $_POST['approver'];

echo $approver; 
echo "<br />";

//echo "It is working <br />";
if ($approver == "Supervisor")
    echo "Supervisor is working <br />";
```

Comment: `var_dump($approver);` -- You probably have spaces or something in the string.

Comment: you're just assuming there's no invisible chars in that string (e.g. spaces, line breaks).

Comment: Amal Murali ,  Marc B   Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It's very possible that you have some whitespace in the `$_POST["approver"]` string. To avoid this, try changing:

```
$approver = $_POST['approver'];
```

to:

```
$approver = trim($_POST['approver']);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! trim() works very well.  Even I can not see any whitespace, there must be some ones.  Does POST function cause that?

Comment: Not normally - double check the code associated with posting the data through because the source is most likely there!

Comment: It is from a url <a href="http://www.universalhairforum.com/u2015/travelExpense/approval.php?id=' . urlencode($id) .'&approver=' . urlencode($approver) . '">Click to review and approve!</a>

Comment: Ben,  Thank you very much!

Comment: I shouldn't think so - double check the output of `$approver` before and after using `urlencode($approver)` to investigate.